# Does pfSense support AMD64?

Tags: freebsd, pfsense

Specifically I'm looking at running it on a node on this hardware:

http://www.supermicro.com/Aplus/system/2U/2022/AS-2022TG-HTRF.cfm

Any gotchas lurking out there?  I'm assuming the AMD soft raid isn't going to fly ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pfSense 2.0, currently at RC1, has a 64-bit (AMD64) build. See their [official FAQ](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Does_pfSense_support_64_bit_systems%3F).

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason pfsense won't work with an AMD CPU -- Whether or not it supports running in 64-bit mode is a matter to look up on the [pfsense website](http://www.pfsense.org/), but I would assume for compatibility reasons that they're running a 32-bit codebase.

Re: the RAID controller in that system, this is again a matter to look up on the [PFSense Hardware Compatibility List](http://www.pfsense.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=46&Itemid=51) -- I don't know whether that controller is/was officially supported by FreeBSD, but there's a good chance that as long as it looks like a regular SATA drive to the OS FreeBSD (and thus pfsense) will be more than happy to use the disks.